# Right to left support instead of some views and it's sub views

Tags: ios, swift, right-to-left, multilingual

I want to make my app Right to left when the language is RTL, I put this line in `AppDelegate`

```
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

It worked, but I want forced some view's to be left to right in both languages I changed these view's `semantic` from `Unspecified` to `Force Left-to-Right` but it doesn't worked.

[image]

Can you recommend me to make it work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

will force all leading/trailing constraints to be right-aligned , so if you want to exclude some views , then you need to make their constraints with left/right , and this by selecting the constraint and toggle it's `respect language direction`